# Цикл с условием bat file

Tags: bat

Первое условие срабатывает, а остальные не срабатывают. Хотя по логике все должно работать.
Батник вызывается с параметрами: my.bat -d 123 -dh 333

```
:while

if "%1"=="-d" ( set WORKDIR=%2 & shift & shift & goto :while )
if "%1"=="--work-dir" ( set WORKDIR="%2" & shift & shift & goto :while )
if "%1"=="-l"( set LOGDIR="%2" & shift & shift & goto :while)
if "%1"=="-log-dir"( set LOGDIR="%2" & shift & shift & goto :while)
if "%1"=="-dh"( set DBHOST="%2" & shift & shift & goto :while)
if "%1"=="--host"( set DBHOST=%2 & shift & shift & goto :while)
if "%1"=="-db"( set DATABASE=%2 & shift & shift & goto :while)
if "%1"=="--database"( set DATABASE=%2 & shift & shift & goto :while)
if "%1"=="-u"( set DBUSER=%2 & shift & shift & goto :while)
if "%1"=="--db-user"( set DBUSER=%2 & shift & shift & goto :while)
if "%1"=="-p"( set DBPASSWORD=%2 & shift & shift & goto :while)
if "%1"=="--db-password"( set DBPASSWORD=%2 & shift & shift & goto :while)
if "%1"=="-j"( set JOBS=%2 & shift & shift & goto :while)
if "%1"=="--jobs"( set JOBS=%2 & shift & shift & goto :while)
if "%1"=="-ld"( set LOGDROP=%2 & shift & shift & goto :while)
if "%1"=="--log-drop"( set LOGDROP=%2 & shift & shift & goto :while)
if "%1"=="-pt"( set PROJECTSTYPE=%2 & shift & shift & goto :while)
if "%1"=="--projects-type"( set PROJECTSTYPE=%2 & shift & shift & goto :while)
if "%1"=="-pn"( set PROJECTNAME=%2 & shift & shift & goto :while)
if "%1"=="--projects-name"( set PROJECTNAME=%2 & shift & shift & goto :while)
if "%1"=="-jc"( set JOBSBATCH=%2 & shift & shift & goto :while)
if "%1"=="--jobs-batch"( set JOBSBATCH=%2 & shift & shift & goto :while)
if "%1"=="-def"( set DEFAULT=YES & shift & goto :while)
if "%1"=="-default"( set DEFAULT=YES & shift & goto :while)
if "%1"==""(set /a POSITIONAL+=%1 & shift & goto :endwhile)

:endwhile
```

Полный код скрипта:

```
wmic csproduct get "UUID">mac.txt

echo %UUID%

SET /P UUID=<mac.txt

set file = mac.txt

set old = "UUID"

more +1 "mac.txt" >"file.txt.new"
move /y "file.txt.new" "mac.txt" >nul

SET /P UUID=<mac.txt



rem For /F "usebackq tokens=* skip=1 delims=" %%i In (%file%) Do Set UUID=%%i
echo %UUID%
pause

:uniqLoop
set "WORKDIR=\bat~%RANDOM%.tmp"
if exist "%WORKDIR%" goto :uniqLoop
echo >"%WORKDIR%"

:: Запись переменной в файл для проверки
echo %perem%

set LOGDIR="./Logs"
set LOGDROP=NO

set DBHOST=localhost
set DATABASE=DAE
set DBUSER=root
set DBPASSWORD=1

set JOBS=0.8

set PROJECTSTYPE=*
set PROJECTNAME=*

set JOBSRECHECK=5
set JOBSBATCH=100

set DEFAULT=NO

for %%a in (%CD%) do set /a cnt+=1
REM echo %cnt%

rem ## worker_start.sh -d tmp - l

set f_sr="-d"

set POSITIONAL=()
:while  

pause

echo %1
echo %2

pause

if "%1"=="-d" ( set WORKDIR=%2 & shift & shift & goto :while )
if "%1"=="--work-dir" ( set WORKDIR="%2" & shift & shift & goto :while )
if "%1"=="-l"( set LOGDIR="%2" & shift & shift & goto :while)
if "%1"=="-log-dir"( set LOGDIR="%2" & shift & shift & goto :while)
if "%1"=="-dh"( set DBHOST="%2" & shift & shift & goto :while)
if "%1"=="--host"( set DBHOST=%2 & shift & shift & goto :while)
if "%1"=="-db"( set DATABASE=%2 & shift & shift & goto :while)
if "%1"=="--database"( set DATABASE=%2 & shift & shift & goto :while)
if "%1"=="-u"( set DBUSER=%2 & shift & shift & goto :while)
if "%1"=="--db-user"( set DBUSER=%2 & shift & shift & goto :while)
if "%1"=="-p"( set DBPASSWORD=%2 & shift & shift & goto :while)
if "%1"=="--db-password"( set DBPASSWORD=%2 & shift & shift & goto :while)
if "%1"=="-j"( set JOBS=%2 & shift & shift & goto :while)
if "%1"=="--jobs"( set JOBS=%2 & shift & shift & goto :while)
if "%1"=="-ld"( set LOGDROP=%2 & shift & shift & goto :while)
if "%1"=="--log-drop"( set LOGDROP=%2 & shift & shift & goto :while)
if "%1"=="-pt"( set PROJECTSTYPE=%2 & shift & shift & goto :while)
if "%1"=="--projects-type"( set PROJECTSTYPE=%2 & shift & shift & goto :while)
if "%1"=="-pn"( set PROJECTNAME=%2 & shift & shift & goto :while)
if "%1"=="--projects-name"( set PROJECTNAME=%2 & shift & shift & goto :while)
if "%1"=="-jc"( set JOBSBATCH=%2 & shift & shift & goto :while)
if "%1"=="--jobs-batch"( set JOBSBATCH=%2 & shift & shift & goto :while)
if "%1"=="-def"( set DEFAULT=YES & shift & goto :while)
if "%1"=="-default"( set DEFAULT=YES & shift & goto :while)
if "%1"==""(set /a POSITIONAL+=%1 & shift & goto :endwhile)

:endwhile

echo "Hello, while is over"
echo "Worker start with options:"

echo %UUID%
echo %WORKDIR%
echo %LOGDIR%
echo %LOGDROP%
echo %DBHOST%
echo %DATABASE%
echo %DBUSER%
echo %DBPASSWORD%
echo %JOBS%
echo %PROJECTSTYPE%
echo %PROJECTNAME%
echo %JOBSRECHECK%
echo %JOBSBATCH%
echo %DEFAULT%
echo %POSITIONAL%

python worker_start.py --work-dir %WORKDIR% --log-dir %LOGDIR% -dh %DBHOST% -db %DATABASE% -u %DBUSER% -p %DBPASSWORD% -j %JOBS% -ld %LOGDROP% -pt %PROJECTSTYPE% -pn %PROJECTNAME% -jc %JOBSRECHECK% -jb %JOBSBATCH% -def %DEFAULT% --UUID %UUID%
pause
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в пробелах.

Вот так:

```
if "%1"=="-dh" ( set DBHOST="%2" & shift & shift & goto :while )
```

(обратите внимание на пробел перед скобкой) у меня `-dh` детектируется.